# Making windows form with CLR and C++ program

Tags: c++, c++-cli, clr

So I have this project called "Detection" written in c++, the project is all set, it has class, function and of course a main function to call all the function and class written in Main.cpp . The problem is, when I want to make GUI using windows form with CLR for this project (that I already made earlier), the MyForm.cpp (default name for windows form) also has main function. So I have some question :

1. How can I overload these main functions?
2. If I can overload them, how can I called the main function in Main.cpp through a button? (after the button clicked, the program run)

I'am very sorry if my questions doesn't make sense because I'am new to CLR and C++. Thank you

Comment: A C++ program, either plain C++ or the managed C++-CLI, can only have a single `main` function. If you need to do two things, then create *two* functions, named differently of course, and call them from the single `main` function.

Answer (score -1):

The approach you take isn't the correct one. Look up how to write functions in c++.

There should be one main function in your programme. Other code should be written in an appropriately named function and called as per required; for eg :

```
public static void main(char[]args){
//initialisation codes only
}

public void onButtonClicked()
{ 
   //your button clicked code 
   onPlaySound();
}

public void onPlaySound()
{ 
   //your play sound code 
}
```

Comment: Hi ir2pid! thankyou for your answer. I know that shouldn't be two main function in a C++ program. That's why I'am asking because I really don't know how to deal with this situation. I already tried to move all function from C++ main to C++ CLR main, but after compiling the error list keep saying "main::function cannot be overloaded".